# How to create a new Record Type using existing Record Type?

Tags: f#, suave

I am trying to create a simple `Todo` REST API using Suave. The `Todo` type is defined as:

```ml
type Todo =
    { id: Guid
      title: string
      isComplete: bool
      deadline: DateTime option }
```

This type works perfectly when using **Get By Id `GET /todos/{guid}`** and **Get List `GET /todos/`** APIs. But when creating a new `Todo` item, the payload doesn't contain `id` property since it will be auto-generated as part of the DB operation. So, following REST API call is made:

```
POST /todos/

{
    "title": "Hello world",
    "isComplete": false,
    "deadline": null
}
```

However, **the problem is JSON De-serialization breaks** as the `id` field is not available. How to handle this scenario? Declaring `id` as `option` doesn't feel right as it is not right abstraction. In TypeScript, I can use Utility Types like `Omit`, `Pick`, etc. to create new types like:

```
export interface Todo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
    deadline?: string
}

// Create new Type from existing type!
export type TodoInput = Omit<Todo, 'id'>;

let payload: TodoInput = {
    isComplete: false,
    title: "Hello"
}
```

How can I achieve similar results in F#?

Comment: I doubt F# has such operations.  You use composition, e.g., `Todo` is a composition of `TodoInput` and `id`.  In composition, I would rename `TodoInput` as `TodoData`.

Comment: This looks like a domain design question. The easy way would be to have two types, one without id and one with the id - this would simplify the design of the code that deals with the records. Create a record NewTodo to capture your input before you send it to the database and a separate Todo to deal with the persisted records.

Comment: I am not familiar with this exact case, but I tend to use anonymous records for (de)serialization in similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to deserialize even if you don't have the id.  The below works fine for me. The id will be Guid.empty.

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

type Todo =
    { id: Guid
      title: string
    }

let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Todo>("{\"title\":\"test\"}")
```